# Is it possible to show input source in top bar with single keyboard layout in GNOME Shell?

Tags: keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, indicator

When we have multiple keyboard layouts, the topbar in GNOME shows indicator like this:
[image]

Is there a way to show the indicator even there is single input source/language?

Running Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 and 19.10.

---

This is an XY problem I am trying to achieve..

I have two shortcuts with below commands

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us')]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'ru')]"
```

[image]

both the commands work great and the shortcuts also works great but it lacks the indicator

Comment: Ok. I don't know how you would do it, but I think there is a more low level command style (described here at Ask Ubuntu) which works on GNOME and which might help.